# Django how to make form fields optional

Tags: python, django

In django how to make form field optional ?

my model,

```
class Student(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email = models.EmailField()
```

Comment: Here is the answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940308/how-to-make-filefield-in-django-optional][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940308/how-to-make-filefield-in-django-optional

Comment: @KamilDębowski - that is for manually created forms, not for forms created automatically from models.

Answer (score 18):

Presuming you want to make `last_name` optional, you can use the [`blank`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#blank) attribute:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField()
```

Note that on `CharField` and `TextField`, you probably don't want to set `null` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8609425/20972) for a discussion as to why), but on other field types, you'll need to, or you'll be unable to save instances where optional values are omitted.

Answer (score 18):

You use the `required` argument, sent in with a `False` value:

`email = models.EmailField(required=False)`

Answer (score 5):

If you want to allow blank values in a date field (e.g., `DateField`, `TimeField`, `DateTimeField`) or numeric field (e.g., `IntegerField`, `DecimalField`, `FloatField`), you’ll need to use both `null=True` and `blank=True`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `null=True` and `blank=True` in your model.

Answer (score -5):

```
class StudentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        exclude = ['first_name', ...]
```

Comment: This doesn't make the form field optional, it just doesn't show up at all in the form.

Comment: @ChrisWesseling yes that's what i thought the OP wanted to do.