# django form field throws error when blank and null are set

Tags: django, django-forms

I have the following form:

```
class PlayerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    crop_coords = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'style':'display:none'}))
    profile_image2 = forms.ImageField()

    class Meta:
        model = Player
```

I try to make these fields optional, like this:

```
class PlayerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    crop_coords = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'style':'display:none'}), blank=True, null=True)
    profile_image2 = forms.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Player
```

I get a strange error:

> ```
> File "/mypath/leagues/forms.py", line 80, in PlayerForm
>    crop_coords = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'style':'display:none'}),
> ```
>
> blank=True, null=True)
>        File "/mypath/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/fields.py", line
>   214, in **init**
>          super(CharField, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs)
>       TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'null'

How can I make this fields not required without receiving this error?

Answer (score -1):

This answer is correct: [How to make FileField in django optional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940308/how-to-make-filefield-in-django-optional)

ModelForms use:

```
required=False
```

Instead of `blank=True, null=True`

Comment: That answer is perfectly correct: it correctly states that you use required in forms, and blank in models.