# Getting user's old image if no image is selected

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a form that takes in user data like bio, profile picture, gender, etc. and upon submission either creates this new row about the user or updates the existing row. This will only work if the user uploads an image. If no image is uploaded for the profile picture, then the form doesn't submit. How can I make it so that if the user didn't upload a profile picture, then it'll keep the user's previous profile picture and still submit?

Here's my code:

```
class ProfileSettings(UpdateView):
    model = Profile
    template_name = 'blog/settings.html'
    form_class = ProfileForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('blog:settings')

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            bio = form.cleaned_data['bio']
            gender = form.cleaned_data['gender']
            avatar = form.cleaned_data['avatar']

            Profile.objects.update_or_create(user=self.request.user, defaults={'avatar':avatar, 'bio':bio, 'gender':gender})

        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.success_url)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you the quick and dirty - 3 places to solve this:

1. Javascript - make the form aware of what fields are required and pre-fill if the username already exists (out of scope from your question but just throwing it out there)
2. In the API endpoint (this seems to be the approach you are going for)
3. In your model (implement a custom save function that looks to see if new, and compare initial value to subsequent value)

I'll dump options 1 and 3 because they aren't pertinent to your question as asked.  I'm assuming user is unique per profile.  And I'm assuming that currently the field avatar is required.  If you set that to not required then the form post should allow a null value for avatar - [How to make FileField in django optional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940308/how-to-make-filefield-in-django-optional).  You may be thinking, but I don't want that field to be possibly blank - you could always enforce that the first time the post is made that the field is set via the API endpoint itself.  If you made that field optional then the form would post but you may want to be more explicit with .update_or_create by actually checking to see if the object already exists and if so require the field or if not confirm that field is set.

Comment: But how do I set the profile picture to their original picture if they submit with no image?

Comment: You currently use this to set or update the value: Profile.objects.update_or_create(user=self.request.user, defaults={'avatar':avatar, 'bio':bio, 'gender':gender})

Comment: The simplest way to is to see if Profile.objects.get(user=self.request.user...) exists and if so if avatar exists then profile["bio"], profile["gender"], profile.save() but don't set avatar.